# Outputting semicolon-delimited rows from php MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling all the details out of my MYSQL DB via PHP and looping that in a simple while loop to write out the output in HTML.

```
$queryDB = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLEA")

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $queryDB ))  

    echo " <tr> ";
    echo "<td ".$td_color." > " . $info['column1'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td ".$td_color." > " . $info['column2'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td align='center' ".$td_color." > " . $info['column3'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td align='center' ".$td_color." > " . $info['column4'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td ".$td_color." > " . $info['column5'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td ".$td_color." > " . $info['column6'] . "</td> ";
    echo "</tr> ";
```

Until recently this works fine, but what has happened as of late is that one of the columns has grown from a simple input to something that contains multiple entries separated by a ;.

For example:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------

ABC      | DEF      | HIG      | 123; JKL | 324      |   345    |

123      | GHK      | GHY      |1 ; 3; KL | 546      |   546    |
```

But reviewing this is a little cumbersome, therefore I want my code to seperate the contents of column 4 and repeate the rows to have singular entries, such as:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ABC      | DEF      | HIG      | 123      | 324      |   345    |

ABC      | DEF      | HIG      | JKL      | 324      |   345    |

123      | GHK      | GHY      |1         | 546      |   546    |

123      | GHK      | GHY      |3         | 546      |   546    |

123      | GHK      | GHY      |KL        | 546      |   546    |
```

I know I probably have to put column 4 into an array but I just don't understand or have the knowledge to piece it all together.

Comment: So you want multiple subvalues from one of the columns (or all of them?) to multiply the result `$row`? Then split that entry and add a second `foreach`. (Or go with "[normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) all the DB things".)

Comment: I agree with @mario, that column could grow and contain more semicolon separated values, which will be difficult to maintain someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where the semicolumn might be, I'd just explode the column and loop through the elements. Something like this might work if you know that the semicolumn is always going to be in column 4:

```
$queryDB = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLEA")

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $queryDB )){  
 $elements = explode(";", $info['column4']);
 foreach($elements as $element){
  echo " <tr> ";
  echo "<td ".$td_color." > " . $info['column1'] . "</td> ";
  echo "<td ".$td_color." > " . $info['column2'] . "</td> ";
  echo "<td align='center' ".$td_color." > " . $info['column3'] . "</td> ";
  echo "<td align='center' ".$td_color." > " . $element . "</td> ";
  echo "<td ".$td_color." > " . $info['column5'] . "</td> ";
  echo "<td ".$td_color." > " . $info['column6'] . "</td> ";
  echo "</tr> ";
 }
}
```

Comment: Even if the string does not contain the delimiter, `explode()` will still return the string.  In this case it will either return multiple elements or one element (if no semi-colon was there).  But let me just say that error handling is always a good thing and making assumptions is always a bad thing.